# Proof that Variance * Degrees of Freedom = RSS

Tags: regression

I'm reading some notes for an course in Econometrics, and they parenthetically assert that the total sum of squares for the null model is equal to the variance * degrees of freedom (n-1), while the residual sum of squares for a given model is equal to variance * degrees of freedom (n-p).

What is the intuition or proof behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Total sum of squares is:
$$ \mathit{TSS} = \sum_{i=1}^n \left( y_i - \bar{y} \right)^2 $$

Sample variance of $y$ is given by:
$$ \hat{\mathrm{Var}}(y) = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n \left( y_i - \bar{y} \right)^2 $$

Residual sum of squares is:

$$ \mathit{RSS} = \sum_{i=1}^n \left( y_i - \hat{y}_i \right)^2 $$

Recall that residual $e_i$ is $e_i = y_i - \hat{y}_i$. The variance of the residuals is estimated as:

$$ \mathrm{Var}\left(e_i \right) = \frac{1}{n-k} \sum_{i=1}^n e_i^2$$

There are numerous posts here on the degrees of freedom correction. Basically, the idea is that your residual vector has $n$ entries but only $n-k$ unique values since the other $k$ are constrained by your estimates of $\beta$.